# Write a file to Resources directorty

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, directory-structure, overwrite

I have file saved in the Resources, in the first time the user run the application. It will use the file in the resources. any other time the app should run a file downloaded already from the internet .
I can download a file from the internet and save it to the document directory.
my question is how can I overwrite the new file on the first file.

if I could write on the Resources directory. it will solved.

*This method returns the file path from the document directory*

```
+(NSString*)filePathFromDocumentsDirectoryForFile:(NSString*)fileName
{
// Define the decumnets directory for the file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,fileName];
}
```

Comment: Resources means app bundle, right?

Comment: yes , its the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to the app bundle. One way to handle this would be to check on every read if the file exists in the Documents directory, and if it doesn't, then use the one from the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

try to use below code :

```
NSString *filePathInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"file Extension here"];

NSString *filePathInDocumentDir = [@"~/Documents/filename.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathInDocumentDir]) {
    // use file from document directory
}else{
    // user file from bundle
}
```

and to store data in Document directory try below code.

```
NSData *data = [NSData new]; //  Assign your data here
[data writeToFile:filePathInDocumentDir atomically:YES];
```

Hope this will help you.